# MongoDB: move elements within a document

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have 4 documents in a **customers** database, under the collection **cust**. Each looks something like this:

```
{
   _id: "123abc",
    first_name: "billy",
    last_name: "boyd"
    ...
}
```

I would like to structure each document like this...

```
{
    _id: "123abc",
    name: {
        first_name: "billy",
        last_name: "boyd"
    }
    ...
}
```

What CRUD operation would help me do this? (Keep in mind that I'm new to MongoDB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator which can be used for `update`, try:

```
db.cust.update({ _id: "123abc" }, { $rename: { first_name: "name.first_name", last_name: "name.last_name" } })
```

or

```
db.cust.updateMany({ }, { $rename: { first_name: "name.first_name", last_name: "name.last_name" } })
```